# How to broadcast HLS using Android MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I'd like to broadcast HLS using Android `MediaRecorder`. I'm going to save [stream to socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFile(java.io.FileDescriptor)) and read from it (known hack to handle live streaming without saving to file). How can i broadcast the stream in HLS? I believe i need to split the stream into HLS chunks. Any suggestions?